# Python Game Libraries

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet, cocos2d-python

**First off please do not mark this topic as a duplicate. All the relevant threads are years old. I would like updated information.**

What are the pros and cons of the following libraries?

I am aware of:

- PyGame, seems to be the most popular but the website is full of
  broken links and no news in awhile.
- Cocos2D Python, Seems good as cocos2D is all the rage right now.
  Almost no support though and the stack overflow pages only seem to
  get a post every couple weeks.
- Pyglet, This is the only one I never tried as Cocos2D seems to use
  Pyglet. Seems to update more then the cocos2D python stack overflow
  but less then the pygame.
- Other? Rate a better library!

I am looking for information on ease of use, preferably pythonic and up to date. But perhaps most importantly active.

Comment: Can the person that marked for close please comment why?

Comment: Recommendations are off topic unforunately

Comment: Reworded to better reflect a question.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad / tool rec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Pygame, Cocos2d, and Pyglet to create a series of games, I would have to recommend **Pyglet**.

Cocos2d and Pygame were very unwieldy. On the other hand, pyglet has a very neat API, enjoyable to work with, and very 'clean'.

It also has no external dependencies, and is wrapped on top of OpenGL, allowing you to do some pretty advanced special effects.

You can view a game (along with the source code) I created with Pyglet [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/4IZH-5rOLm0).

Answer (score 2):

Pygame and Pyglet are definitely on the radar.

#### Pygame

Great, popular game engine. No support for a variety of file types. But it's no longer maintained.

#### Pyglet

Very powerful, high support for many files. Thorough documentation. OpenGL support, intuitive.

#### Cocos2D

I really feel that Coco2D is just an unnecessary medium to use the underlying Pyglet engine.

Comment: If you didn't quite understand my opinion, it's hands down Pyglet.